# How do I make my app "approvable" for the app store after rejection?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app on the App Store called System of A Down app.

Yesterday, while having submitted the new version, ( which fixed a critical bug ) I submitted for a Expedited App Review. I got a message my app was "In Review" in iTC.

One day later, ( Yes, the review took one day ) it got "Metadata Rejected"

I mentioned "System of A Down" which apparently is a copyrighted brand according to Apple.

I can't mention System of a down in my app, by the /whole/ app is dedicated to them.

> > 8.5
> >
> > We found your app includes features or content, in the title, keywords, and/or imagery, that bear a resemblance to the well-known, third-party mark, System of A Down. In order to proceed with the review of your app, we require documentation evidencing you are authorized by System of A Down to use features from System of A Down. Additionally, it would be appropriate to adjust the title of your application so that the trademarked title is used as a descriptor, but not as part of the product name. For example, the following styles are acceptable formats for names: GreatApp - "for System of A Down" GreatApp - "System of A Down edition" GreatApp - "System of A Down version" Please remember that pursuant to your agreement with Apple, you represent and warrant that your application does not infringe the rights of another party, and that you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim that your application infringes another party's rights. Moreover, we may reject or remove your application for any reason, in our sole discretion. Accordingly, please provide documentary evidence that you have the rights to use this content to ensure compliance with the iOS Developer Program License Agreement. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with your app review. While your iTunes Connect Application State is displayed as Rejected, it is not necessary to upload a new binary if you only need to address issues in your metadata. However, if you need to address compliance issues in your app - and not just its metadata - and you are able to make the necessary changes, we encourage you to do so and resubmit your binary for review.If your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. In iTunes Connect > Manage Your Applications, select your app and click View Details. - Click Edit in the Metadata section - Revise the desired metadata values - Click "Save" at the bottom of the screen - Once you click Save, you will see the "Submit New Metadata" button in the top right. Click "Submit New Metadata" If your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary. NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App Localizations by clicking the Edit button next to each localization.<<

The first version however, DID get accepted. Now the question is, should I reject the Binary, and re-upload it in the hopes someone else reviews it and approves it?

I can't not mention system of a down in a system of a down app...

Or what is the best way to get this update approved?

Here's the Metadata :

> > Do you want all the info on System of A Down?

Their Demo tapes, Released albums, unreleased albums, videos, biography, tour dates and way more are all in this app!

Features of this app :

All 5 Demo Tapes
All info on Toxicity II ( Unreleased Album )
All info on Storaged Melodies ( Collection of unreleased songs and demo's )
All Videos ( Play directly )
Lyrics on all the videos
Play the Demo Tapes directly ( iPad only )
All 5 Studio Albums
All info on Advance ( Collection of unreleased songs )
Tour Dates
Biography

Way more amazing features planned for updates.

Amazing interface and great info - 4/5 - AppReviews Netherlands

Simply Amazing - 5/5 - My Mom

-This is a modern app, which uses gestures on iPhone and iPad instead of the old tap-bar. Swipe through the interface while you're listening to their Demo tapes in the background. ( This is has been been developed in iOS 6 Required for iPhone.

DISCLAIMER : I, Sam Guichelaar do not own, control, or endorse any of the information, Names, Groups, bands, or services linked or referenced to a Third Party in my app. No Copyrighted Images were used unless properly edited. No Copyrighted names were used, without permission. What's New in this Version - Added a option to re-view the tutorial.

-Bug Fix : Fixed an issue on the iPhone version where the user had to kill the app and relaunch before the content became visible. Thanks to Jarl and @gameshack_ for reporting this bug.

-Memory leaks fixed<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the Apple guys put it, you can't use a third-party mark in your application without consent from the owners, It's like trying to make a game with Nintendo's Mario in it without Nintendo's consent.

The fact that it got approved before beats me